# Get variable $_GET with ajax

Tags: php, sql, ajax, get

I'm trying to build an ajax live search.

index.php

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Search</span>
        <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    load_data();
    function load_data(query) {
        $.ajax({
            url:"new/new_fetch.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{query:query},
            success:function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
     }
     $('#search_text').keyup(function() {
         var search = $(this).val();
         if(search != '') {
             load_data(search);
         } else {
             load_data();
         }
    });
});
</script>
```

new/new_fetch.php

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "dbname");
if(isset($_POST["query"])) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE category_parent = '".$_GET['category']."' ORDER BY subcategory";
}
```

But I have an `Undefined index: category in new/new_fetch.php` error.

My code works without WHERE operator.

How can I get `$_GET['category']` using ajax POST method? thx

Comment: You cant. You need to use ajax GET method.

Comment: Also, why rebuild the wheel: http://vdw.github.io/HideSeek/

Comment: you send data:{query:query} there's no 'category' in there

Comment: Your code is [wide open to SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/5828/pdo/2685/preventing-sql-injection-with-parameterized-queries)

Comment: Thx all, I will check [wide open to SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/5828/pdo/2685/preventing-sql-injection-with-parameterized-queries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you never passed the category variable in the AJAX. What you need to do is something like below:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"new/new_fetch.php",
    method:"GET",
    data:{
        query:query,
        category:"SOME_VALUE"
    },
    success:function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to accept both $_GET and $_POST I recommend you to use $_REQUEST it covers both get and post.

Comment: @Rubyx  Sure.. Ping me if you need further help

Answer (score 0):

To pass data using both the GET and POST method, you can add the GET method variables directly to the URL as follows:

```
var strCategory = "category1Data";
var passURL = "new/new_fetch.php?category=" + strCategory;

$.ajax({
    url:passURL,
    method:"POST",
    data:{query:query},
    success:function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
    }
});
```

This code will submit the form using the POST method but append variables to the URL that can be captured using the GET method.